# Does poison resist matter for Speaking with Silence?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, when working on the *Speaking with Silence* quest for the Thieves' Guild, you end up sedated by a poisoned arrow while Mercer and Karliah discuss the good old times.

Considering vampires have a 100% resistance to poison, would being a vampire in that situation make any difference?

Answer (score 2):

**No** it would not,game uses "trigger" to sedate you.It works on engine basis not gameplay basis.

There is just too much things that can go wrong if they equipped someone with 1st poison arrow and left it to attack first enemy,what if someone gets there and conjures creature to be hit by an arrow first?

Not to mention the character specifications as items,levels,bonuses,resists...

Comment: I'm not sure you understood. What I meant was if it would make any difference story-wise. I'm asking if the developers considered the possibility that the player's a vampire.

I'll assume not, since then the whole story would have to be changed... somewhat.

Comment: You assume right,the game tries to ignore how you develop your character(race,vampire or not,class...),only dialogue options can change the flow of the story.

Answer (score 0):

The story changes for YOU. The game doesn't change to a point where you cannot advance because you are a vampire. However, you will have to play the game differently (ie Feed/murder people, hide from the sun, so on). Some NPCs will see you as a threat.

Comment: Read the wrong question. But no, I don't think they've considered the possibility that the player is a vampire in that case. But as I play through and considering the level of detail they've placed in this game... I wouldn't be surprised if they did add an alternative content if you were a vampire during that quest.

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you link to the bottom left area of your answer, you'll see an "edit" button. This will allow you to modify your question so you can edit in your comment.